# Как в DJANGO вывести миниатюры thumbnail по умолчанию?

Tags: django, thumbnails

Господа, помогите, не могу добиться вывода миниатюр thumbnail по умолчанию. Хотя всё делаю один в один по документации. Получается какой то бред.

Вот моделька:

```
class Descriptions(models.Model):
    ....
    description=models.TextField()
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    ....
```

Вот шаблон:

```
{% load thumbnail %}
...
<img src="{{ description.image|thumbnail_url:'cit' }}" alt=""> # Этот код работает! Но он не по умолчанию. По нему вопросов нет.
{% thumbnail description.image|default:'images/photo21.jpg' 50x50 %} # А вот этот не работает! По нему вопрос.
```

В шаблоне первая строчка работает, а вот вторая, которая по умолчанию должна выводить миниатюру не работает, в браузере вместо изображения на его месте выдается вот этот бред:

/media/thumbnails/images/photo21.jpg.50x50_q85.jpg

Что за это такая строка с тремя точками ?? Как сделать вывод миниатюры по умолчанию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, в Django нет тега `thumbnail`. Стоило указать, что вы используете библиотеку solr-thumbnail. Во-вторых, в документации вы не найдёте такого применения тега. Вот пример из документации:

```
{% thumbnail item.image "40x40" crop="80% top" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```